# problem importing kivy. Missing attribute 'deps'

Tags: python, installation, kivy

I'm just installing kivy and try to run the code: `import kivy`

But i get this error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\school\lek_mapp\django_tot\test.ipynb Cell 1 in ()
----> 1 import kivy

File c:\Users\mikae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py:340, in 
    338 import kivy.deps
    339 _packages = []
--> 340 for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(kivy.deps.__path__):
    341     if not ispkg:
    342         continue

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'kivy' has no attribute 'deps' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'm using VScode for this.

I have tried to uninstall kivy and reinstall it but with no succsses. I also tried to manully remove all the folders and reinstall it again but still nothing. And my file name is test.ipynb

Comment: did you `pip install kivy` ?

Comment: yes, im a beginner at programing so its all a bit new to me

Answer (score 1):

Kivy is not working in jupyter notebook environment as far as I know.
This is a message I have encountered using jupyter notebook in VSC.
So I changed to a normal python file and everything is fine.